# readElements XML with XmlReader and Linq

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

My aim is to read this xml <strike>file</strike> stream:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<events>
    <header>
        <seq>0</seq>
    </header>
    <body>
        <orderBookStatus>
            <id>100093</id>
            <status>Opened</status>
        </orderBookStatus>
        <orderBook>
            <instrumentId>100093</instrumentId>
            <bids>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1357.1</price>
                    <quantity>20</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1357.0</price>
                    <quantity>20</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1356.9</price>
                    <quantity>71</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1356.8</price>
                    <quantity>20</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
            </bids>
            <offers>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1357.7</price>
                    <quantity>51</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1357.9</price>
                    <quantity>20</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1358.0</price>
                    <quantity>20</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1358.1</price>
                    <quantity>20</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
                <pricePoint>
                    <price>1358.2</price>
                    <quantity>20</quantity>
                </pricePoint>
            </offers>
            <lastMarketClosePrice>
                <price>1356.8</price>
                <timestamp>2011-05-03T20:00:00</timestamp>
            </lastMarketClosePrice>
            <dailyHighestTradedPrice />
            <dailyLowestTradedPrice />
            <valuationBidPrice>1357.1</valuationBidPrice>
            <valuationAskPrice>1357.7</valuationAskPrice>
            <lastTradedPrice>1328.1</lastTradedPrice>
            <exchangeTimestamp>1304501070802</exchangeTimestamp>
        </orderBook>
    </body>
</events>
```

I created (based on the post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/24/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2.aspx
a function

```
public IEnumerable<XElement> readElements(XmlReader r, string matchName)
    {
        //r.MoveToContent();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            switch (r.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    {
                        if (r.Name == matchName)
                        {
                            XElement el = XElement.ReadFrom(r) as XElement;
                            if (el != null)
                                yield return el;
                        } break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

which I planned to use in the following way

```
            IEnumerable<XElement> xBids = readElements(xmlReader, "bids");
            publishPricePoint(xBids, "bids");
            IEnumerable<XElement> xOffers = readElements(xmlReader, "offers");
            publishPricePoint(xOffers, "offers");
```

where the method publishPricePoint looks like this:

```
    public void publishPricePoint(IEnumerable<XElement> ie, string side)
    {
        PricePoint p = new PricePoint();
        var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
        ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

        var bids = (from b in ie.Elements() select b).ToList();
        foreach (XElement e in bids)
        {

             p.price = decimal.Parse(e.Element("price").Value, ci);
             p.qty = int.Parse(e.Element("quantity").Value, ci);
             OnPricePointReceived(this, new MessageEventArgs(p, side));
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that in this piece of code:

```
            IEnumerable<XElement> xBids = readElements(xmlReader, "bids");
            publishPricePoint(xBids, "bids");
            IEnumerable<XElement> xOffers = readElements(xmlReader, "offers");
            publishPricePoint(xOffers, "offers");
```

only first two lines work, ie. only bids can be read, not the offers. What is wrong with this? For me, it looks like, there XmlReader disappears after bids have been read.
Thank you for help

================== Other solution =================

```
  while (xmlReader.Read())
  {
  #region reading bids
            if (xmlReader.IsStartElement("bids"))
            {
                readingBids = true;
                readingOffers = false;
            }

            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && xmlReader.Name == "bids")
            {
                readingBids = false;
                readingOffers = false;
            }

            if (readingBids == true)
            {
                if (xmlReader.IsStartElement("price"))
                    price = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsDecimal();

                if (xmlReader.IsStartElement("quantity"))
                {
                    qty = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                    OnPricePointReceived(this, new MessageEventArgs(price, qty, "bid"));
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region reading offers
            if (xmlReader.IsStartElement("offers"))
            {
                readingBids = false;
                readingOffers = true;
            }

            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && xmlReader.Name == "offers")
            {
                readingBids = false;
                readingOffers = false;
            }

            if (readingOffers == true)
            {
                if (xmlReader.IsStartElement("price"))
                    price = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsDecimal();

                if (xmlReader.IsStartElement("quantity"))
                {
                    qty = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                    OnPricePointReceived(this, new MessageEventArgs(price, qty, "offer"));
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: have you tried switching both statements... so frist offers then bids?

Comment: yes of course. Does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you do something like this

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml"); 

    var bidResults = (from br in document.Descendants("bids") 
                       select br).ToList();  
    var offerResults = (from or in document.Descendants("offers") 
                       select or).ToList();
```

then you can just iterate with a `foreach (Xelement element in bidResults)` to get all the data of the bids and also the data from the offers

```
foreach (XElement xElement in returnResult) 
   {       
    Offer off = new Offer();  
    off.price = xElement.Element("price") != null ? xElement.Element("price").Value : "";       
    off.quantity = xElement.Element("quantity") != null ? xElement.Element("quantity").Value : "";            
  }
```

Comment: I cannot read the whole file as XDocument, as it comes as a stream. I have to read it as it comes. I came up with other solution (see edited question)

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to close and reopen the XmlReader.  It simply is in EOF state.

Your solution requires reading everything twice, not too efficient.

Unless your XML is very large (eg  > 100 MB) it would be much faster to read it all into an XDocument and filter the bids and offers out with Linq.

Edit: OK, so your data is continuously streamed. That means you can't use a single-tag filter, you'd be skipping the others.

- A basic idea: Read every element, with XElement.ReadFrom()
- push the elements you want into (separate) queues.
- you'll want asynchronous processing. Use the TPL or the (beta) async/await features.

Comment: The problem is, I cannot load the whole xml because it comes as a push message from a server so I should read it on the continous basis.

Comment: I also came up with other solution (see edited question), but am not sure if this is better, because if I wanted to read more elements, the code would get very big.

Comment: A basic idea: Read every element, with XElement.ReadFrom()
How should this be done? I think this was my aim in the first version of the code, but looks like it did not work as it should...